# Как рассчитать вращение игрока в зависимости от направления движения

Tags: c#, математика, геометрия

Всем привет. У меня есть сервер, который должен расчитывать вращение игрока в зависимости от его направление движение в 3d используя System.Numeric.Vector3 и System.Numeric.Quaternion.
Затем мне нужно сериализовать Quaternion на сервере и послать его на Unity клиент(что уже сделано). В Unity я могу использовать метод Quaternion.LookRotation, но в c# нету такого метода и приходиться расчитывать все самому.

Как я могу расчитать угол вращения и сформировать из него правильный System.Numeric.Quaternion?

Comment: Например по [формулам](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кватернион)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я нашел формулу по этой [ссылке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кватернионы_и_вращение_пространства) . Но все еще не понимаю как мне сделать вращение по одной оси(например Y в unity).

Comment: По вашей же ссылке: ``Вращение на единичный кватернион...`` ``вращает вектор v на угол α вокруг оси u....``

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков тогда не совсем понятно как расчитать угол, на который нужно повернуть объект. Для меня это немного темный лес и википедия не очень с этим помогает. Не могли бы вы написать ответ с разъяснением пожалуйста?

Comment: Тогда непонятно какие данные у вас есть чтоб расчитать угол

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков направление движения и координаты объекта.

Comment: Направление и угол по вашему не одно и то же(ну либо легковычислимое значение)?)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков вопрос и состоит в том, как это можно подсчитать.

Comment: По теореме [Пифагора](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Теорема_Пифагора) А точнее по теореме [косинусов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Теорема_косинусов) если лень самому формулу выводить из пифагора... п.с. развернутый ответ с разъяснением проходят в школьной программе, почитайте школьный учебник геометрии